# MacOS 14 disabled Menus for Java 17 applications (Sometimes...)

Tags: java, macos, menu

We have a large java app that has been working on Mac OS for many years, through multiple version of Java as well.

Now, with Mac OS 14, and Java 17, on SOME Macs, the Menus get disabled after using a dialog.  All the Menus.

This isn't happening using Mac OS 13.

I've checked our Menu enabling code just to be sure, and as far as we know, the Menus are still enabled.

Any suggestions on how to at least figure out what is happening?  (oh, and, of course, it works just fine on my Mac, but always fails on the users Mac.)

Comment: What kind of menus?  What GUI framework?  And if you have “menu enabling code,” I would definitely suspect that as the first culprit.

Comment: Umm, this is a Java Application.  That has a Main Menu - which on MacOS is the menu at the top of the screen.  Kinda like every other Mac OS application.  We do use Swing for the GUI.
ALL apps have some menu enabling code - unless every menu item is always enabled, which is highly unlikely in any non-trivial application.
This code WORKS on some Mac OS 14.1 machines, and not on others.

Comment: Oh, and I did check source control  We haven't changed any of our menu handling code.
This works just fine in earlier releases of Mac OS.

Comment: Are these application menus provided by OSX, or JMenus created by your code?

Comment: It's Java, so we do use JMenu

Comment: Is the menu handling code enabling/disabling the menus in the AWT event dispatch thread, like it’s supposed to?  If a program alters Swing components outside of that thread, unpredictable behavior is the result.  Often, it will work simply because the program got lucky.  (This really would be easier if you would edit your question and include that code.)

Comment: Yes, we are very careful to do UI work in the AWT event thread.

Comment: So far, we've only found 1 Mac that this fails on.  We have NO IDEA why it fails on just this one Mac.  (We finally got other people to test this.)
The mac has the same corporate software as all the others.

For now, we've given up, and will wait to see if any real users hit this problem.

Comment: When you say the menus get disabled, does that mean they’re grayed out, as if `setEnabled(false)` was called on them?  Or is it that they don’t respond to the mouse?